# Linux - starting a visible terminal on boot

Tags: linux, terminal, debian, raspberry-pi, crontab

I have a C program I wrote for debian on the raspberry pi that asks the user to enter a number, 1-4 which it then stores in a configuration file. This only happens if the configuration file is missing. I'd like to run this program on boot. Problem is, I can get it to run on boot, but haven't had any luck getting the terminal window to show up so I can see it. I've tried editing /etc/rc.local and adding commands there. I've tried editing crontab. I've tried all the tricks with "export display=:0 && command". Any suggestions?

#### Edit:

Here is the command I am actually running in /etc/rc.local:

```
x-terminal-emulator --command=/opt/vc/src/hello_pi/initialConfig/./initialConfig.bin --display=:0
```

The program uses scanf() to capture keyboard input and display feedback.

Comment: Have you disabled X server authentication with `xhost +` ? (You probably don't want to just do this and leave it like this, but it's a quick and dirty trick to see if this is your issue)

Comment: No luck with your suggestion. I added my actual command in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. In your users home directory you have to create a file called autostart at the path /.config/lxsession/LXDE/ and just add whatever command you want to execute after login to the autostart file.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't talking about "on boot" but rather about "on X startup", and this is a complicated thing because in a *typical* setup what's started by X is a login manager, i.e. there's no user session yet even after X is started; only after a user logs in, a session is initiated.

So, my take on this:

- If you have a kiosk-style setup, where there are no user sessions at all, just something is to be started along with X, don't reinvent the wheel an go with [`nodm`](http://packages.debian.org/nodm) which allows to run arbitrary script after setting up a graphical interactive session for a pre-configured user.
- If you have a "normal" (i.e. typical) setup then the even you're trying to hook onto is misplaced: you have to somehow hook into a graphical interactive user's session.

  Here things start to get complicated:

  - If you have some display manager (`*DM`, typically `GDM`, `KDM`, `XDM`, `slime` etc) then first study which hooks they provide — some of them are capable to execute certain scripts after a user logs in.
  - If you have a "modern" `d-bus`-enabled session setup (GNOME etc), then consider if you're able to listen to a certain an-interactive-user-session-created event on the system `d-bus` instance — you could supposedly hook onto it at boot time after the system `d-bus` instance starts.